# Converting list of Hex Codes to Seaborn Color Palette

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn

I'm trying to convert a list of hex codes to an `sns.color_palette` and then using it as a color palette for a bar plot -

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
colors = sns.color_palette(['#f15a22', '#9db1bb', '#f26b38', '#f47b4e', '#f58c64', '#f79c7a', '#bb1d8d', '#f8ad91', 
                            '#00aeef', '#fbcebd', '#fcded3', '#feefe9', '#c23498', '#fbca8e'])
sns.barplot(organizations.index, organizations.values, color=colors)
```

But this keeps returning me an error - 
`ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument`.

The hex codes work fine when I use them as `sns.palplot(colors)`, and I've checked that the number of color codes are also equal to the number of bars (data rows) to be produced.

Can someone please tell  me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My bad! It should be

```
palette = colors
```